# visual studio blend adaptive trigger button missing?

Tags: uwp, blend

I'm following along with a blend tutorial and it says some stuff about adaptive triggers, but the button to edit the triggers isn't there. Do I have to change a setting? What stuff do I need installed?

Sorry if there isn't enough information here, I'm not very familiar with visual studio yet.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B878d.png)

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT it's the short one on the visual studio YouTube channel. (https://youtu.be/tbulRaoc7ow)

Comment: And provide your Visual Studio detail version and the uwp target version as well please.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I'm using Community 2017 15.7.3. The target version is Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134). I made an Imgur album that I think has everything on it. https://m.imgur.com/a/X9yCXMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. By testing on my side, if you change the UWP app target version to 15063 or lower, the adaptive trigger button can work well.If you do want to use this feature in 17134, you could try to implement it by XAML code. Please reference [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger) .

You could also report this issue with Blend Visual Studio feedback. Click `Help->Send Feedback->Report a problem` in the menu bar.